# "The system cannot find the file specified" in Visual Studio C++. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm a very beginner in Programming.
Visual Studio shows an error "**the system cannot find the file specified**" in C++ when I add two or more C++ files under Source Files.
I reinstalled visual studio 2019 and still getting the same errors.
Single C++ files run smoothly.

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

Comment: You have two `main` functions defined which makes your program ill-formed. The error message even tells you that you have two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not able to find the executable Project1.exe because your program didn't compile successfully which is probably due to the two main functions you have defined.